# Error in is.finite=(x) : default method not implemented for type "list"

Tags: r

I am returning the error "is.finite(x):default method not implemented for type "list""

I am trying to plot these co-ordinates onto each quadrant to assess the usefulness of each action. I would also like to add a legend with the name of each event as a colour. Here is my code:

```
Df<-structure(list(ï..Idea = structure(c(2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Find motivation online", 
"Reward yourself for tidying room", "Schedule: communication", 
"Schedule: Diary", "Schedule: phone", "Start as soon as you see mess"
), class = "factor"), Effort = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L), Impact = c(7L, 
4L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 6L), Topic = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "Project Tidy Room", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
install.package("ggplot2")
install.package("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

x_mid<-mean(c(max(Df[2],na.rm=TRUE),min(Df[2],na.rm=TRUE)))

y_mid<-mean(c(max(Df[3],na.rm=TRUE),min(Df[3],na.rm=TRUE)))

Df %>%
mutate(quadrant = case_when(Df[2]>x_mid & Df[3]>y_mid ~ "Q1",
                          Df[2]<=x_mid & Df[3]>y_mid~"Q2",
                          Df[2]<=x_mid & Df[3]<=y_mid~"Q3",
                                              TRUE ~"Q4")) %>%

ggplot(aes(x=Df[2],y=Df[3],colour=Df[1]))+geom_vline(xintercept = x_mid)+geom_hline(yintercept=y_mid)+geom_point()
```

Comment: I see I should add a comma to my data frame selection, and designate the data frame in gg plot

Answer (score 0):

I found a much easier solution without quadrant labels:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Df,aes(x=Df[,2],y=Df[,3],color=Df[,1]))+geom_point()+labs(title="Effort vs 
Impact",x="Effort",y="Impact")+scale_x_continuous(breaks=(0:10),limits = 
c(0,10))+scale_y_continuous(breaks=(0:10),limits=c(0,10))+geom_hline(yintercept = 
5)+geom_vline(xintercept = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Was resolved by restarting Rstudio.